# How can I link a hst:sitemenu to a ftl?

Tags: freemarker, hippocms

I am trying to link a menu to his correspondent ftl and I don´t understand which are the proper steps I have to take. I didn´t found any usefull documentation about it. All the help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to retrieve the menu in a component and put that on the request. In the ftl you can then reference the menu. You can use the [essentials menu component](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/content/v14/docs/menu-component) or the [dynamic menu component](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/content/v14/docs/dynamic-menu-component). Or you have a custom component. I'd suggest starting an archetype project and installing the simple content from essentials. This should add a menu that you can look at to see how it works.

An [example](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/content/v14/docs/add-the-secondary-navigation-menu-to-the-about-page) from one of our online [tutorials](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/content/v14/docs/build-a-website) looks like this:

```
<#include "../include/imports.ftl">
<#if menu??>
  <div class="hst-container">
    <div class="hst-container-item">
      <#if menu.siteMenuItems??>
        <#list menu.siteMenuItems as item>
          <#if item.selected || item.expanded>
            <div class="list-group left-nav">
              <a href="<@hst.link link=item.hstLink/>" class="list-group-item level1">${item.name?html}</a>
                <#list item.childMenuItems as item>
                  <a href="<@hst.link link=item.hstLink/>" class="list-group-item level2"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"> </i>${item.name?html}</a>
                </#list>
            </div>
          </#if>
        </#list>
      </#if>
    </div>
  </div>
</#if>
```